# How to go to next input by pressing enter in soft keyboard in android web-view phonegap build

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have one application which is build with phonegap and kendo UI as a js framework. The form inside the application is irresponsive for the enter button pressed on soft keyboard. Ideally pressing should move to next input as far as I know. but pressing enter button here is doing nothing.  This is is not the code where I am working exclusively so my question is

1) How to achieve this across the application?

2) Is there any old code which is preventing the desired behavior?

3) Can I replace Enter with Go button across the application? But in last input ideally it should be enter button.

I wish I could put some code here but I don't have any for this context. 
The screenshot looks like this. 
[image]
I am looking something like this

```
  $('input[type="textbox"]').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }});
```

Comment: you should do this in your webpage

Comment: can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

just add these two lines

```
 android:inputType="textPersonName"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

it worked for me.

Comment: need to add this line in html form? and inputType="textPersonName" here person name is random or linked to class and id?

Comment: But I am not developing native application. its js based phonegap build

Comment: @jaydeepmarvaniya you just have to add these in the xml where the 'EditText' is defined

Comment: sorry bro, I am just not using xml based declaration. its html form.